# setEditable and isEditable

Tags: objective-c, macos, methods, parameters

Hi I'm new to objective c and I see this quite often when I read the developer documentation.

There are methods named setEditable or setWhateverName and isEditable or isWhateverName

What is the difference between the set"blabla" and is"blabla"

and example would be for the NSButton Class

```
-setAlternateTitle
```

and `-alternateTitle`

or

NSImageView class

```
-isEditable
```

and `-setEditable:`

I think that the latter in both examples takes a paramater and the former ones do not. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

These are called [*mutator methods*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method).  They are methods you use for accessing various [Objective-C *properties*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17), which are basically class member variables (so-called *ivars* or *instance variables*), except you can't access them directly.  You can only access the ivars through the *setter* and *getter* methods.

The *getter* method gets the current value of the property.  It's usually given a name identical to the property in question (such as `-alternateTitle`) for non-boolean properties, or the name with an `is` prefix (such as `-isEditable`) for boolean properties.

The *setter* method sets a new value for the property.  It's usually given a name of the property name prefixed with `set`, e.g. `-setEditable:`.

For example:

```
if ([myObject isEditable])  // Is the object editable?
    /* do stuff */ ;
...
[myObject setEditable:YES];  // Make it editable
```

Answer (score 1):

`-setAlternateTitle` and `-alternateTitle` are the default setter and getter (e.g. `NSObject` or `int`), based on standard naming conventions.

`setEditable` and `isEditable` is the conventional setter and getter for boolean (`BOOL`) properties. In the boolean case, it improves readability. Note that the variation here is only in the getter.

Answer (score 1):

There is a pattern to settlers and getters.

For non BOOL ivars

- the setter has a "set" prefix: "setMyIvar" -- note the upper case
  "M".
- the getter is simply the ivar name: "myIvar" -- notice there is no "get" prefix.   *

These are the defaults created by the property, ex:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) (NSString *)myString;
```

For BOOL ivars there are two patterns:

- the setter has a "set" prefix: "setMyBoolIvar" -- note the upper case "M".
- the getter is simply the ivar name: "myBoolIvar" -- notice there is no "get" prefix.   *

  or
- the setter has a "is" prefix: "isMyBoolIvar" -- notice there is no "get" prefix and the upper case "M".

These are the defaults created by the property, ex:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) (BOOL *)myBoolIvar;
```

or respectively

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, getter=isMyBoolIvar) (BOOL *)myBoolIvar;
```